# IE7 & IE8 frameset onload only fires on first use

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, onload, frameset

I have a htm page called launch which is within the same directory as a JavaScript file. The launch.htm page contains the frameset which has an onload function called initalise() which is a method within the JavaScript file.

The frameset onload function works fine on any load in IE9, IE10 and IE11. However it only works on first load in IE7 & IE8. I debugged it and found out that the initalise() method in the frameset onload is not found on any load after the first. Below is my code:

```
<head><title>Launching Caring for your Customer</title><script type='text/javascript'     src='Client.CourseProperties.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>var a = document.createElement('script'); 
a.type = 'text/javascript';a.src = domain + '/scripts/Client.Launch.Scripts.min.js';a.async =   false;
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(a, s);
var ss = document.createElement('link'); ss.rel = 'stylesheet';ss.href = domain +  '/content/comm.min.css';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; s.appendChild(ss); </script></head>

<frameset id='Launch' onload='initialise();'  cols='0,*' frameborder='0' framespacing='0' border='0'>

<frame src='Blank.htm' id='content' name='content' frameborder='0' framespacing='0' border='0' scrolling='no' />
<frame src='Blank.htm' id='present' name='present' frameborder='0' framespacing='0' border='0'   scrolling='no' /></frameset>
</html>
```

What I have tried so far: Re-adding the onload function to the frameset, didnt work. Creating the frameset on the fly, there was code in the JavaScript file which requires the frameset to by static so this didnt work either.
Any help will be appreciated very much :).

Comment: I think nobody cared about your question basically because you didn't provide a reproduction scenario. Post some code in JsFiddle.net so we can play with your error by our own.

Comment: I was starting to wonder haha. I dont think I will be able to provide an example :(. This is part of the backend of a cloud SCORM course. The course itself is uploaded to an LMS which login is required. The course needs to be loaded from a domain that is in my domain database for the cloud SCORM courses to make sure the course is being fired from a valid domain. I could create a test login but dont think my manager would let me do it unfortunately.

From your response I'm guessing that the onload frameset issue its not a common issue in IE7 & IE8?

Comment: Actually not my area of expertise. But I've just went all the way down in the SO list and your question was there with not much attention.